# SQL - Integer Type - Detect bit

Tags: mysql, sql, bitwise-operators

With SQL, I would like to detect if a certain bit is on with an integer column type (MySQL)?

How would I go about this?

Basically, I want to detect if a bit is on, if it is on, then ignore.

I am using something like this now:

```
WHERE (column & 2) != 2
```

Comment: Are you talking about a bit column or an integer column?  What do you mean by on?  Please rephrase the question.

Comment: Bitwise flags are fine for enums in 3GLs but a 4GL such as SQL works best with relational data i.e. relations of tuples with attributes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Say you're checking for the 3rd bit then...

```
SELECT bits & 8 = 8 FROM table;
```

This returns a binary (1 or 0) for whether the bit in question (in this case the third) is on or off for each row in the column 'bits'.

using 2^x for the xth bit instead of 8.

for example, to check the 5th bit we would use 2^5 = 32

```
SELECT bits & 32 = 32 FROM table;
```

However, this is needlessly complicated. Simply use boolean values in several columns and it will make things much easier.

Comment: What exactly is SELECT bits & 8 = 8 FROM table;  doing? We are selecting bits & 8 = 8 for a column?

Comment: The basic idea is that the '&' operator determines the bits that are 'on' in both of its arguments. So (bits & 8 = 8) determines if 8 (which is just the third bit) and the column 'bits' have corresponding bits.

The result of the query as a whole is a series of Binary results for if the third bit is on.

Comment: Sometimes you might want to use like 20 boolean fields on one record, then bitwise kinda makes sense

Answer (score 8):

Use `&`, the [bitwise AND operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx):

```
SELECT ID, myfield
FROM mytable
WHERE (myfield & 16) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL supports the standard bit operators:

```
DECLARE @BitMask INT
SET @BitMask = 34

SELECT 
    @BitMask & 32, -- Returns 32, ON 
    @BitMask & 16  -- Returns 0, OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

For mysql, you can use the bit-wise `AND` operator `&` with a bit mask

For example, to get a boolean `true` if bit 2 (counting from 0) is set for column1, use this:

```
where (column1 & 4) = 4
```

this will work for multiple bit checks, for example to check that both bits 0 and 2 are set:

```
where (column1 & 5) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You should tag the question for the database platform that you are using.

If this is SQL Server 2008, you could use bitwise operators (specifically bitwise or equals) to compare to an integer whose bits are set to the pattern you are interested in testing for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc627409.aspx

Note that by packing integers this way, you are likely preventing the use of any indices on those columns.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you achieve what you want:

[SQL bit manipulation](http://weblogs.asp.net/bdill/archive/2008/01/05/integer-based-bit-manipulation-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL, 1 = true, 0 = false.
In MS Access, -1 = true, 0 = false.
...
Maybe someone can fill-in for the other dialects.

If you're interpreting a bit in an application layer, you should be able to use a conversion function (e.g., in vb you might say `IF convert.toboolean(myValue) THEN...` to interpret true or false.